# EF Generic Repository Pattern - Insert/Create Method Issue While Inserting Root Entity with Sub Entities

Tags: c#, insert, entity-framework-6, primary-key, repository-pattern

```
public class A
{
    string Id {get; set;}
    string Property_1 {get; set;}
    string Property_2 {get; set;}

    // Foreign Key for Class B
    string B_Id {get; set;}
    // Many to One Relationship
    B objectOfClassB {get; set;}

    // One to Many Relationship
    ICollection<objectOfClassC> listOfClassC {get; set;}
}
```

We have an Object of Class A, that we are trying to insert. We are also passing Values for Class B & Class C (List) which are sub entity of Class A.

While inserting, we want to check first whether sub-entity i.e. values of ObjectofClassB is not present in the database table. If it is present just add the Foreign Key of the same to Class A Table.

So how could we prevent Detaching or Not Inserting only objectOfClassB (sub-entity)?

Note - I want to insert listOfClassC (another sub-entity)

Comment: FYI, The above Class A object will be passed from Controller/Service Layer. The Code at Repo Layer will be Generic and will use (T entity) for CRUD Operations. We want to make the required validations at Repo Layer.

Answer (score 0):

First you check whether there is B Class in the Database
ex:

```
var b = dbContext.B.FirstOrDefault()
if(b != null)
{
A.objectOfClassB = b;
//.. do something else or persist
}
```

For adding the collection objectOfClassC
just add it to A.listOfClassC and when you add
"A" to the db EF will create objectOfClassC entities in the DB for you.

Comment: Stefan, the problem here is, We are using Generic Repository Pattern due to which we are not able to get the specific object. We need to strictly work with (T entity). Please find below the Insert Code in Repo -  public bool Insert(T entity)
{
 bool flag = false;
 try
 {
  if (entity == null)
  {
   throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
  }
  this.Entities.Add(entity);
  this._context.SaveChanges();

  flag = true;
 }
}

Comment: I really can't understand what's the problem, here. if you want to stick with this GRP implementation and validate in the repository layer, you should either inherit it and overwrite the insert method or pull ObjectOfClassB in the service layer, do whatever business logic you want and persist ObjectOfClassA.

Comment: Provide more information about where exactly is the problem when it occurs and what do you want to happen and all the code involved